# How to make custom shapes in Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, css-shapes

Instead of inserting a shape.png, I want to create a custom shape in Dreamweaver. Can I create a shape using code? Please see the image attached.

[image: Custom Shape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using CSS. You can Watch Many [SHAPES HERE](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)...

When You need a Curvy Borders (As shown In the Shape.png ) Use

```
Border-radius:10px
//Or other properties are there!
```

Hope So You Know Css and its properties.

I have simple program for simple curve ...

Css file:

```
.box{
  width:500px; height:100px;  
  border:solid 5px #000;
  border-color:#000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
}
```

Html file:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Output:

[image]

You can make many Shapes using CSS...